# TCP connection resets, when ARP response is not coming in time

Tags: sockets, tcp, arp

I have a machine which is connected to the server which is outside of network.
Recently I am observing too many issues in connectivity in between them.
Recently I have upgraded my machine's OS from Windows XP to Windows 7, and after this I am observing this issue.

To analyze the problem better, I have taken the Wireshark logs from the machine. Wireshark traces of the scenario can be found at [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFTbi.jpg) link

Machine: 142.6.78.2 
Gateway: 142.6.78.1 
Server: 172.25.2.3

I am suspecting this issue is because of ARP response from gateway is not coming on time and hence machine is resetting the connection.
Also Machine always sends RST, after 4 ARP broadcast requests.

I want to know, if there is any significance of ARP response and RST being sent?
If yes, then how can I configure my machine to send RST after say 10 ARP broadcast requests?

Please suggest!!

Comment: You can't, I hope, and you don't want to. You should find out what is wrong with the ARP requests and fix that problem.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR You IP addresses are mess, check network topology.

### What happened

My interpretation of your traces:

- at some point PC wants to send packet to server. However, server is in different subnet, packet should be transferred through router, so PC needs to know MAC address of router beforehand.
- since MAC address isn't in the cache (cache is freed if not used for long enough), PC sends several ARP requests "hey, router, what is your MAC"
- for whatever reason router doesn't reply for more than 12 seconds. This is REALLY abnormal.
- then router finally sends its MAC, PC sends "reset connection" to server. Probably, PC initially wanted to send "keep-alive" packet to check connection status, but 12 sec delay thanks to the router resulted in connection timeout. This is pure speculation though.

### What caused

Unclear, but you have weird things going on:

- Server is in [private network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) 172.25.xxx.xxx, so PC must be in the private network as well. Otherwise you can't reach private network from global IP address.
- However, PC and router are in something like 142.6.78.xxx subnet. These are global IPs, which are seemed to be used as private, since PC can eventually reach server. Invalid setup.
- Moreover, traces include ARP request for 172.21.228.1, which PC can't receive while staying in 142.6.78.xxx subnet. This means PC with global IP is not only in local subnet, it is somehow in the same subnet as 172.21.xxx.xxx devices.

Probably, this stuff can be explained by two network cards on PC and wireshark sniffing on both, too few info even for speculations.